# Changing data in linkedlist java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to change the data portion of a node, but I am getting a cannot find symbol error on my sets and gets for the WordItem class. The first part is the object class and the containsWord is in the LinkedList class. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public class WordItem implements Comparable {
    private String word;
    private int count;
    private ArrayList<Integer> atLines;

    public WordItem(String word, int c, int atLine) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = c;
        this.atLines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        atLines.add(atLine);
    }


    @Override
     public int compareTo(Object other) {
      WordItem w = (WordItem)other;
      return w.getWord().compareTo(this.word);
      }

    public String getWord() {
        return this.word;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count){
      this.count = count;
   }
   public void setAtLines(int line){
      this.atLines.add(line);
   }
```

---

```
public boolean containWord(String word, int atLine){
    Node curr,prev;
    boolean flag = false;
    prev = head;
    for(curr = head.next; curr != null; curr = curr.next){
        if(word.equals(curr.data.getWord())){
            ArrayList<Integer> ara = curr.data.getLines();
            for(int i = 0; i < ara.size(); i++){
                if(ara.get(i) == atLine){
                    curr.data.setCount(curr.data.getCount() + 1);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            curr.data.setAtLines(atLine);
            curr.data.setCount(curr.data.getCount() + 1);
            return true; 
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the specific error you are getting and highlight which line number it is at?

Comment: I Assume that your `data` within your `Node` is a `WordItem`. Can you please check the code you posted for `WordItem` as it does not seem complete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems in the code. I ran it and I can't reproduce the error.

It might be that your IDE got stuck. Try to Clean/Build and if that doesn't help try resetting/clearing the cache (google for that, how to do that is different with every IDE).

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, there is no method `WordItem#getLines()`.

I assume that you may have just not copied all the code in your question, but just to make sure that you do have this method within your `WordItem` class

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getLines(){
     return atLines;
}
```

If not then the following line

```
ArrayList<Integer> ara = curr.data.getLines();
```

will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe have a little typo somewhere, if you see the definition of the error: http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm
That may be the problem